# how to handle local and public ip using boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp

I have following 3 eth  as follows :

```
    

eth0      inet addr:10.105.159.146  Bcast:10.105.159.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe11:84e1/64           

eth1      inet addr:192.168.56.102  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe5e:8a5c/64          

lo        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
```

This is my code as follows :

```
server::server(const std::string& address, const std::string& port): io_service_(),
            signals_(io_service_),
            acceptor_(io_service_)
        {

            signals_.add(SIGINT);
            signals_.add(SIGTERM);
           #if defined(SIGQUIT)
            signals_.add(SIGQUIT);
           #endif // defined(SIGQUIT)
            signals_.async_wait(boost::bind(&server::handle_stop, this));

            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_);            
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(address, port);
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);

            acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
            acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
            acceptor_.bind(endpoint);
            acceptor_.listen();
            start_accept();
        }
```

what address should i need to pass in

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(**address**, port);
```

so that client can connect using both ip either 192.168.56.102 or 10.105.159.146

currently if i am running as

```
server s("127.0.0.1", "1025");       //lo
server s("192.168.56.102", "1025"); //eth1
server s("10.105.159.146", "1025"); //eth0
```

this all belongs to same machine so how should i run my server or what change i can do so that it should be accessible from client for any IP request of above.

Comment: try 0.0.0.0 as an IP address

Comment: You need either INADDR_ANY (binds to all addresses) or listen on several sockets separately. You don't need the resolver, it translates names to addresses and you already have all the addresses you need. Construct the endpoint from just the protocol and the port number.

Comment: Thanks bopah , its work for me by setting ip to 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set address to "0.0.0.0" to accept all IPV4 addresses. Or you can simply replace:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_);            
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(address, port);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
```

with:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port);
```

Please note that in the line above, port is an `unsigned short` not a `string`.

Comment: Thanks you all for quick response, setting IP to 0.0.0.0 solved my issue as bopah.